# Return both instance id and prediction from predict() method of a Keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensor, tensorflow-estimator

Supposing I have a Keras model which is already trained. When using predict() method, I want to get the instance key value and corresponding prediction at the same time( I can pass key value as a feature/column in the input).

I wonder is it realistic to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this for a while. I'm using the `tf.data.Dataset` infrastructure so my first approach was to see if I could ensure that the order of the examples produced by the datasets was deterministic, but that wasn't optimal because it gave up a bunch of the parallel processing performance benefits and ended up not being the case in any event. I ended up processing predictions using `model.predict_on_batch` feeding in batches iterated out of the dataset manually instead of feeding the entire dataset into `model.predict`. That way I was able to grab the ids from the batch and associate them with the returned prediction.

I was surprised there wasn't a more ready made solution to a problem that must come up a lot. I haven't gotten up to speed on the `Estimator` interface or custom training/prediction loops yet, but hopefully this problem becomes trivial there.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Since you can associate ids with returned predictions for a single batch using `predict_on_batch()`, I wonder why can not you associate all the ids with all prediction results using `predict()`?

Comment: I think you would have to get the ids from a separate run through the dataset since for the predictions you just feed the whole dataset into model.predict. If the examples come out in a different order on that separate run through the dataset, they won't like up with the predictions. Having said that, it is possible to get the  examples to come out in the same order. The default on tf.data.Dataset.list_files is to shuffle the read order, but you can specify shuffle=False. For what it's worth, in my case there wasn't a big difference in inference duration between predict and predict_on_batch.